# Im after a jquery plugin like this

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, draggable

Hi I am after a jquery plugin to achieve the effect seen on http://www.maxmedia.com/ the ability to click and drag around a container with momentum.

I couldnt find it anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to find a plugin, but if you added the jQuery UI library they have a lot of drag and drop functionality build it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to acheive that effect using [jQuery Ui Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback) and applying a delay on the transition.

Comment: I managed to find it, originially i was searching with the wrong terminoligy http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll for anybody else that wants to achieve the effect you get on the iphone, ipad etc

Answer (score -1):

if you watch into the javascript you can find a library called jquery overscroll, it is used to obtain the innertion of dragging. 
You can find it here: http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll